# How to get data from Quizlet without API using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cors, access-control

The Quizlet API has been dead for a while but I want to work on a project that uses their study sets. I spent a while trying to find an API to use but there were many misleading claims; some say the old API works but you need an access token (which there is no way to generate) and some say it doesn't work. I figured out that I'll need to do the extra work without an API and create a backend that gets the HTML from Quizlet and gets the cards from that. I did look for packages such as `quizlet-fetc` and `quizlet-fetcher` but neither of them worked. This has been a lot more difficult than expected because Quizlet seems to be blocking requests, and `Request failed with status code 403` keeps getting logged when I make a request. Below is the code I have so far and I would appreciate any advice.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const https = require('https');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

// Proxy server
proxy.on('error', function(err, req, res) {
  console.error(err);
  res.writeHead(500, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.end('Error');
});

// Allow all origins to access this API
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

// Fetch the HTML for a Quizlet set
const fetchQuizletSet = async (url) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    },
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    })
  };
  const response = await axios.get(url, config);
  return response.data;
};

// Parse the HTML for a Quizlet set and extract the card data
const parseQuizletSet = (html) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const title = $("h1.PageTitle-heading").text().trim();
  const cards = [];
  $(".SetPageTerms-term").each((index, element) => {
    const front = $(element).find(".SetPageTerm-wordText").text().trim();
    const back = $(element).find(".SetPageTerm-definitionText").text().trim();
    const image = $(element).find(".SetPageTerm-media img").attr("src");
    const audio = $(element)
      .find(".SetPageTerm-media audio source")
      .attr("src");
    cards.push({ front, back, image, audio });
  });
  return { title, cards };
};

// Define a route to handle Quizlet set requests
app.get('/quizlet-set/:setId', async (req, res) => {
  const setId = req.params.setId;
  const url = `https://quizlet.com/${setId}`;
  try {
    const html = await fetchQuizletSet(url);
    const data = parseQuizletSet(html);
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios in the code you posted fails getting past cloudflare and so just gives the error `Request failed with status code 403`. It can be solved using [puppeteer-extra](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra)  like in the code below.

package.json : add the following

```js
"puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2"
```

code : [sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBR9Q.jpg)

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

// Allow all origins to access this API
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

// Fetch the HTML for a Quizlet set
const getQuizletSet = async (url) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
      '--window-size=1920,2700',
      '--lang=en-US,en;q=0.9'
    ]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');
  await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    timeout: 30000
  });
  await page.waitForSelector('script[id=__NEXT_DATA__]');

  let raw = await page.$eval('script[id=__NEXT_DATA__]', el => el.textContent);
  let parsed = JSON.parse(raw); // check this or dehydratedReduxStateKey below if you need anything more from the page
  parsed = parsed.props.pageProps;

  let result = null;

  try {
    const { setTitle, canonicalUrl, socialImageUrl, dehydratedReduxStateKey } = JSON.parse(raw).props.pageProps;
    const terms = Object.values(JSON.parse(dehydratedReduxStateKey).setPage.termIdToTermsMap);
    const cards = terms.map(({
      word: front,
      _wordAudioUrl: frontAudio,
      definition: back,
      _definitionAudioUrl: backAudio,
      _imageUrl: image
    }) => ({
      front,
      frontAudio,
      back: back.replace(/[\r\n]/gm, ''),  // remove line breaks
      backAudio,
      image
    }));

    result = ({ url: canonicalUrl, socialImg: socialImageUrl, title: setTitle, cards: cards });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  browser.close();
  return result;
};

// Define a route to handle Quizlet set requests
app.get('/quizlet-set/:setId', async (req, res) => {
  const setId = req.params.setId;
  const url = `https://quizlet.com/${setId}`;
  try {
    const data = await getQuizletSet(url);
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0');
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked once. Now when I try fetching from the server, the error `An error occurred trying to load the resource.` in the Network tab. The server console shows no errors. I'm not sure why it worked once then stopped.

Comment: @Globe I just tried 10 different queries 688027875, 665940037, 752373053, 730733603, 687402392, 693576267, 656579725, 784293906,778748788, 780114243 at once to check for problems, but all returned results without an error, so not sure what problem you are getting is, you can change `headless` from true to false in the code to see what is going on as it'll open the page in chromium.

Comment: non existing values return `Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded` as the `__NEXT_DATA__` script doesn't exist on the 'Hmm, looks like you're studying old notes...' page that shows up, and passing nothing returns `Cannot GET /quizlet-set/` apart from these couldn't get it to give me another error yet.

Comment: I found that the issue only occurs when trying to use the same set multiple times. That's why your code worked once and only once, I was using the same setId. The way to fix that was to add the `Cache'Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0'` header.

Comment: Tried the same set/setid multiple times and still don't get an error... which is interesting but if `cache-control max-age=0` fixes it in your case then all is OK, I've updated the code as suggested.